# Jquery Mobile JSON Listview

Tags: jquery

I have the following JSON returned:

`{"aaData":[["Vision Plaza","KE ","JKIA","KE ","Myself"],["987 Avenue","KE ","654 Avenue","KE ","Laptops"],["Merimela","UG ","Nairobi","KE ","Antiques"],["Ngong Road","KE ","JKIA","KE ","Walter"]]}`

These are four records i.e

This is the first record `["Vision Plaza","KE ","JKIA","KE ","Myself"]`,
This is the second record `["987 Avenue","KE ","654 Avenue","KE ","Laptops"]`,
This is the third record `["Merimela","UG ","Nairobi","KE ","Antiques"]`,
This is the fourth record `["Ngong Road","KE ","JKIA","KE ","Walter"]`,

How do I display these records in a listview with each record in its own listview node (li)?

Comment: Can you provide an example of an <li>...</li> populated with sample data please?